# Python for Everybody Chapter 11 Exercise 2 'float' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

So here is my question

Exercise 2: Write a program to look for lines of the form:
New Revision: 39772
Extract the number from each of the lines using a regular expression and the findall() method. Compute the average of the numbers and print out the average as an integer.
Enter file:mbox.txt
38549
Enter file:mbox-short.txt
39756

Code:

```
import re

rev = []

fname = input('Enter file: ')
try:
    fhand = open(fname)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print('File cannot be opened: ', fname)
    exit()


for line in fhand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    rev_temp = re.findall('^New Revision: ([0.0-9.0]+)', line)
    if not rev_temp:
        for val in rev_temp:
            val = float(val)            # Convert the strings to floats
            rev = rev + [val]           # Concats new values

rev_sum = sum(rev)
count = float(len(rev))
rev_ave = rev_sum / count

print(rev_ave)
```

This is the output

```
Enter file: mbox-short.txt
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-c4c50e707989> in <module>
     19             rev = rev + [val]           # Concats new values
     20 
---> 21 rev_sum = sum(rev)
     22 count = float*(len(rev))
     23 rev_ave = rev_sum / count

TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

Why?

Comment: The code you posted and the code in your error output aren't the same.  There are no doubt differences elsewhere that caused the problem that we can only guess at.

Comment: Somewhere up above in what you didn’t show us, you named a variable `sum`. The fix? Don’t do that.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

From what I can tell, it looks like the approach you were using was not properly handling lines that were found using the matching pattern. Instead, it was trying to do something with the number only if it didn't exist, which is why you would get a "divide by zero" error.

However, we can modify your code to instead look at all matching strings for all the matches and append those parsed numbers as floats. Then from there, your summing and averaging works fine without error.

```
import re

rev = []

fname = input('Enter file: ')
try:
    fhand = open(fname)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print('File cannot be opened: ', fname)
    exit()

for line in fhand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    #print(line)
    rev_temp = re.findall('^New Revision: ([0.0-9.0]+)', line)
    for x in rev_temp:
        rev.append(float(x))


rev_sum = sum(rev)
count = float(len(rev))
rev_ave = int(rev_sum / count)
print(fname, ':', rev_ave)
```

I get the following for the file names:

```
mbox.txt : 38549
mbox-short.txt : 39756
```

I sourced the file names from:
https://www.py4e.com/code3/mbox.txt
https://www.py4e.com/code3/mbox-short.txt

Comment: Hi, you’ve certainly improved the code—but you didn’t actually answer their question: why am I getting this error? Note that it’s not a `ZeroDivisionError`. It’s a `TypeError`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you inadvertently overrided the built-in `sum` with an indentically-named `sum` variable somewhere.  Look for:

```
sum = <some float value>
```